# How to save ParentComponent form data to database along with nested ChildrenComponents List (to-do-list) data?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

How to Save Angular form data with the following steps:

**1.** Gather ParentComponent data, build new object from that data called **Goal** and save that object to the database (firebase)

**2.** Retrieve the 'auto generated Firebase ID' from newly generated new **Goal** which is generated by Firebase so that I can pass that ID as a foreign key to each ChildComponent instance (I will need that foreign_key for other future operations)

**3.** Gather nested ChildrenComponent form data (each ChildComponent is called **Task**), build objects with that data, and save that data to the database. (each ChildComponent is generated with addNewTask method inside HTML Goal Form here https://pastecode.io/s/7gefx66o)

This is the visual representation of creating the new Goal from my app -> https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ejahr2imrehoblrse6l5w/save-nested-tasks.mkv?dl=0&rlkey=0x8rv4ts924tj116p7rqxntt6

Form HTML: https://pastecode.io/s/7gefx66o

This is my attempt (method inside ParentComponent):

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    // STEP 1 //

    this.newGoal = new Goal(
      form.value.name,
      form.value.isMainGoal,
      form.value.details,
      form.value.select_category,
      form.value.creationDate,
      form.value.endDate
    );
    this.goalsService.postGoal(this.newGoal)

    // STEP 2 //
    // now I need to retrieve the ID from newly generated Goal 
    // which is generated by Firebase - picture below - so that I can pass 
    // that ID (for instance the key NXRfRxIITiDUpggZQbv as a foreign_key to each ChildComponent instance
```

[image]

```
    // STEP 3 //
    .subscribe((newGoalId:any) => {
      this.accordion_items.toArray().forEach(item => {
        form.value.taskPriority = this.priority.nativeElement.querySelector('.active').innerText;
        this.newTask = new Task(
          newGoalId,
          form.value.taskName,
          form.value.taskDescription,
          form.value.taskPriority,
          form.value.taskDate,
        );
        this.tasksService.postTask(this.newTask);

      });
      // ...other stuff here like refreshing goals list etc.

    })

  }
```

Comment: you will want to use this [context provider](https://dev.to/this-is-angular/react-context-in-angular-i4a) functionality